# Plot the specific rows on the same graph

Tags: r

I use that function to plot all of the rows from my data frame into pdf file.

```
library(gplots)
# open the pdf file
pdf(file='Plots of all rows.pdf')

x <- 1:(ncol(tbl_alles)-1) 

for(i in 1:nrow(tbl_alles)){
  # plot onto a new pdf page 
  plot(x=x,y=tbl_alles[i,-1],type='b',main=tbl_alles[i,1],xlab='X',ylab='Y')
}

# close the pdf file
dev.off()
```

How to just plot like 3 rows on the same graph with different colours ?

As a legend use the name of the row...

my data:

```
> dput(head(tbl_alles))
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `20` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `52.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `81` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0), `110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `140.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `189` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `222.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), `278` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `340` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `397` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `453.5` = c(0, 0.66069369, 0, 
    0, 0, 1), `529` = c(0, 0.521435654, 0, 0, 1, 0), `580` = c(0, 
    0.437291195, 0, 0, 1, 0), `630.5` = c(0, 0.52204783, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), `683.5` = c(0, 0.52429838, 0, 0, 0, 0), `735.5` = c(1, 
    0.3768651, 0, 1, 0, 0), `784` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `832` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `882.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `926.5` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `973` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1108` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1200` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("10", 
"20", "52.5", "81", "110", "140.5", "189", "222.5", "278", "340", 
"397", "453.5", "529", "580", "630.5", "683.5", "735.5", "784", 
"832", "882.5", "926.5", "973", "1108", "1200"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", 
"at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01220.1", "at1g01420.1", "at1g01470.1"
), class = "data.frame")
```

That's an output which I would like to see. Just put both plots on the some graph with different colours.

[image: Number 1]

[image: Number 2]

Edit:

```
    > tbl_alles[1066,]
                10 20 52.5 81 110 140.5 189 222.5 278 340 397 453.5 529 580 630.5 683.5 735.5 784 832
    at3g01510.1  0  0    0  0   0     0   0     0   0   0   0     0   0   0     0     0     0   0   1
                882.5 926.5 973 1108 1200
    at3g01510.1     0     0   0    0    0

> tbl_alles[2269,]
            10 20 52.5 81 110 140.5 189 222.5 278 340 397 453.5 529 580 630.5 683.5 735.5 784 832
at5g26570.1  0  0    0  0   0     0   0     0   0   0   0     0   0   0     0     0     1   0   1
            882.5 926.5 973 1108 1200
at5g26570.1     0     0   0    0    0

> tbl_alles[109,]
            10 20 52.5 81 110 140.5 189 222.5 278 340 397 453.5 529 580 630.5     683.5     735.5
at1g10760.1  0  0    0  0   0     0   0     0   0   0   0     0   0   0     0 0.5707348 0.8569183
                  784 832 882.5 926.5 973 1108 1200
at1g10760.1 0.9070698   1     0     0   0    0    0
```

That's what I would like to achieve:

[image: Combined 3]

Comment: rowsToPlot<-c(rowA, rowB, rowC);   for(i in rowsToPlot) where rowsToPlot are integer indeces

Comment: Can you paste my the whole code using an answer option ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you understand that those three rows will give two lines along zero, and one line that has a couple points in the middle?

Comment: Look at my edit. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah I was just saying that you didn't provide data to make that plot, but I think I got it now.  One sec

Comment: Would be great if you solve it. Need to prepare couple of such graphs for the presentation tomorrow...

Comment: Just the same problem like previously `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"        # close the pdf file
        dev.off"`

Comment: missing parens at the end of matplot(, I'm doing this quickly feel free to check it yourself too!

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out alone aswell. Sorry, but unfortunately another problem occurs which I can't solve on my own `Error in df[rowsToPlot, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: have you initialized df?  In my example I did df<-structure.... then ran the code.  Try changing df to whatever the name of your data frame is

Comment: Sorry, of course I put the wrong name of my data... It looks like you solved the problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62208/discussion-between-dmt-and-shaxi-liver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always forget about matplot, I'm not familiar with gplot, so I think it fits this well

Here's a small df I made to replicate your problem

```
df<-structure(list(`10` = c(-0.371350351694367, -1.25087314646208, 
-0.657843532649542), `20` = c(-1.1851240454548, -2.78219491586262, 
0.710133251591709), `52.5` = c(1.68304915266843, -0.496047552485386, 
0.450948253352661), `81` = c(0.129735967979554, 0.254350517817915, 
-0.18288033694209), `110` = c(-1.13792416656106, 0.685305257987392, 
-0.00333217347885503), `140.5` = c(-3.60035706471287, 0.147934251860607, 
1.21899119774361), `189` = c(0.20579357437275, -0.287714362235557, 
-0.116174227557464), `222.5` = c(-2.27228706498774, 1.14330151676478, 
0.437320821753322), `278` = c(0.0184198982292088, 1.03280897369263, 
-0.809374548090546), `340` = c(1.10314005160547, -0.423635755487127, 
1.69263287858465), `397` = c(1.11000715987197, -0.666713965188873, 
-0.616331157049669), `453.5` = c(-0.21763982556254, -0.668405154120432, 
-0.101290244002727), `529` = c(-1.23612437632145, 0.596727546451954, 
1.65926804193271), `580` = c(-1.36914007441172, 0.553436632958187, 
0.370452646201169), `630.5` = c(-1.28739943545904, 1.51605377604701, 
0.535674548844182), `683.5` = c(0.0380431318762389, 0.259944835916881, 
-1.12267356731606), `735.5` = c(0.307116139352162, 0.619942543650423, 
1.43847332323359), `784` = c(0.517011770731407, -0.271348876993244, 
0.382706886840812), `832` = c(0.358756221875511, 0.902328658122764, 
2.19653579973421), `882.5` = c(0.60565816196684, -1.69443962691366, 
-0.338433483486653), `926.5` = c(2.15044754686289, -0.979574461038407, 
0.116260893315264), `973` = c(-1.3051680247044, -0.735063827396212, 
-1.55018820456708), `1108` = c(-0.108476761260576, 1.21094890415222, 
-1.04130290709525), `1200` = c(-0.963125050259433, -1.12921931676616, 
-0.357160373571803)), .Names = c("10", "20", "52.5", "81", "110", 
"140.5", "189", "222.5", "278", "340", "397", "453.5", "529", 
"580", "630.5", "683.5", "735.5", "784", "832", "882.5", "926.5", 
"973", "1108", "1200"), row.names = c("at1g01050.1", "at1g01080.1", 
"at1g01090.1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Now your code, notice I use matplot, transpose the df, convert it to a matrix (for matplot), and specify a type for each of the data sets we'll be plotting

```
library(gplots)
# open the pdf file
pdf(file='Plots of all rows.pdf')



rowsToPlot<-c(1,2,3)
# plot onto a new pdf page 
matplot(as.matrix(t(df[rowsToPlot,])),type=rep("l", length(rowsToPlot)), col=rainbow(length(rowsToPlot)))


# close the pdf file
dev.off()
```

And my picture

[image: Graph]

Comment: Yeah, that's fine but I wanted to plot all of them on the same graph just with different colours :).

Comment: for different colors, add the parameter col=i to the plot, I updated the answer

Comment: That I found out but the general problem with that code is that every plot ( I mean line) is in the next graph on different page of pdf file. I want all of them on the same graph on one page :). Thanks for your patience.

Comment: ok got it, so just take out the for loop, and use the vector of indeces as the row input.  I'll update the answer.  No problem on the multiple shots at this, keep giving feedback and we'll figure it out!

Comment: That I already tried but I got an error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. I `dput` my data in first post to make it easier to find out the problem.

Comment: That seems to hint at a problem in the data itself, can you post a couple rows of your dataframe?

Comment: ok I think I get the problem.  The plot.data.frame function plots columns versus rows.  You can make your problem very simple by transposing the dataframe in the plot, I'll rewrite the answer

Comment: Great, looking forward for that! Thanks!

Comment: @ShaxiLiver ok give that a shot.  I tried plotting your posted data but much of it looked to be boolean values so it wasn't particularly interesting

Comment: Something is not fine with the code because it gives an error: `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                                                                         # close the pdf file
                                                                         dev.off"`

Comment: @ShaxiLiver missing a couple parens at the end of the plot call, that's been fixed

Comment: I edited my first post to show you what I expect to get. So I would like to just put those two plots on the same graph and in the future just add some more. The script which you write gives me a strange graph. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: which rows are those?  In your posted data only row 2 has data that is not simply 1 or 0

Comment: There are from the middle of this data. Anyway, when I used your script for those rows it doesn't look like that. Please try to put any two plots on one graph. In a second I will give you the rows which I am mostly interested in, right now.